# Assigning values to fields in a 2D array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a relatively simple problem that my Google-fu hasn't managed to solve that I think must have a solution.

I have a m-by-n array of values, and I am trying to assign them to fields in a m-by-n structure. This is trivial using a for loop (shown below), I am just wondering there a better/more efficient way of doing it.

```
values = rand(4,8);

for i = 1:4
    for j = 1:8
        val_struct(i,j).a = values(i,j);
    end
end
```

Since I need to do this for a lot of fields, I am a bit reluctant to just run through a bunch of for loops if I don't absolutely need to.

Comment: As [rahnema1 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50939947/7328782), struct arrays are not at all efficient. Why do you need to index as `val_struct(i,j).a` rather than `val_struct.a(i,j)`? [The latter is **much** more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828853/7328782).

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50400758/7328782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) and [`struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) :

```
val_struct = struct('a', num2cell(values));
```

Note that numeric arrays are much more efficient than `struct arrays`.

Comment: Thanks, as I found out the hard way, numeric arrays are much more efficient and I had to recode my problem for numeric arrays anyway. But your answer absolutely does work.