# Vectorisation of structure allocation

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure, vectorization

I am trying to assign a non-constant cell-array value to a field throughout a structure.

I've written a for-loop script that achieves this:

```
n = 5;

c = {[0,0]};
b(1:n) = struct('c',c);

for i=1:5
    b(i).c(1) = i;
    b(i).c(2) = i+1;
end
```

but would like to be able to vectorise the allocation of c.

Is it possible to vectorise this code, or would I be better off using numerical arrays?

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400998/7328782

Comment: If you can use numerical arrays then do that, they will be much faster. I'm not aware of a method to speed up the struct creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorised solution to fit the example you provided, notice that is was created for you example but can be easily generalised using the same logic

Using your code we get the following output:

```
for i=1:5
    disp(b(i))
end

c =
   1   2
c =
   2   3
c =
   3   4
c =
   4   5
c =
   5   6
```

The vectorised implementation is:

```
cc = [1,2];
cc_rep = repmat(cc, n, 1);
increm = 0:1:n-1;

cc_rep_in = cc_rep + increm';
cc_rep_in_cell = num2cell(cc_rep_in, 2);

bb(1:n) = struct('c', cc_rep_in_cell);

for i=1:n
    disp(bb(i))
end
```

and we get the following output:

```
c =
   1   2
c =
   2   3
c =
   3   4
c =
   4   5
c =
   5   6
```

> *Notice* for small `n` your loop is a bit faster, but as it increased the suggested method is faster (first line is your loop, while the
>   second is the suggested code):
>
> for n=10:
>
> ```
> Elapsed time is 0.0005548 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 0.00261188 seconds.
> ```
>
> for n=100:
>
> ```
> Elapsed time is 0.0033648 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 0.00180006 seconds.
> ```
>
> for n=500:
>
> ```
> Elapsed time is 0.021843 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 0.00321412 seconds.
> ```